# In HTML/JavaScript, how do you dynamically set a header/paragraph element's text without overwriting anything else?

Tags: javascript, html

When you search for how to set a paragraph or header element's text dynamically, you keep coming across pretty much the same line of code:

```
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "some text";
```

This isn't entirely correct though.  Take the following example:

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <h1 id="header" />
        <p id="p1" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "header";
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "p1";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first JavaScript line pretty much deletes `p1` from the page, even though `p1` and `header` have nothing to do with each other in the raw HTML.  When wrapping the second JavaScript line in a try...catch block, the error that's caught is:

```
document.getElementById(...) is null
```

The same problem exists when you use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.  I'm a little surprised that everybody is saying that this is how you're supposed to change the text of an element when it really doesn't suit that purpose very well.  What's the right way to set this up?

Comment: your HTML is invalid for starters, `<h1>` and `<p>` aren't self-closing tags. It should be `<h1 id="header">A heading</h1>` etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p` and `h1` are not "empty elements", meaning they're not closed in the same tag that opens them (like `img` and `br`). If you write them like that, they're not valid tags and the browser will ignore them (which is why `document.getElementById` can't find them). Try this instead:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="header"></h1>
        <p id="p1"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "header";
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "p1";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your html to this :

```
 <h1 id="header"></h1>
 <p id="p1"> </p>
```

And try your JavaScript code now they will work, because they are not empty elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue you are having is with the way you are setting up the closing tags like so: `<h1 id="header"/>` with **/** instead of a closing statement. This is incorrect and you need to close it like so: `<h1 id="header"></h1>` The same is true for the `<p>` tag and many others. There are some exceptions to this rule which you can find here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

Here is an example fiddle with the actual result!

http://jsfiddle.net/nd3Dq/